# Postgresql parse string values to integers

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, sql-in

Is there a way in Postgres I can parse string values to integers? Basically I'm trying to query one table (let's call it `table_one`) using values from another table (`table_two`) in a `character varying` column.

Say `SELECT char_column FROM table_two` results in `"2,4,6,8"`, I'd like to use this result in a second query as;

```
SELECT column FROM table_one WHERE some_id IN (2,4,6,8)
```

How can I get the string `"2,4,6,8"` to values `2,4,6,8` so as to be able to use it in the second query?

I've tried casting and to_number functions to no success.

Comment: as it is your question is not clear, please update it with schema, sample data and desired output: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT column
FROM table
WHERE other_column = ANY(string_to_array('2,4,6,8', ',')::INT[])
```

Comment: Thanks, I've been struggling with this for a while now.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
SELECT column     FROM table    WHERE other_column IN (
                           SELECT NULLIF(i,'')::int 
                             FROM regexp_split_to_tables('2,4,6,8',',') t(i)
                         )
```

Explanation:

The part `regexp_split_to_tables('2,4,6,8',',')` will split the string into a table. Then you cast it into integer.

Hopefully it will help you.